# Is it legal to use an official version of Adobe products in commercial purposes? I mean, using Flash for designing games, for example

Tags: flash, adobe

Is it legal to use an official version of Adobe products in commercial purposes? I mean, using Flash for designing games, for example...

Comment: Of course it is. There are lots of commercial Flash based games out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adobe products have EULA items similiar to other IDEs and tools used to generate output.

Basically Adobe owns the copyright and intellectual property of the tool's internals (so you can't use their libraries to go create a new CS5) However, you have full use of the outputs of their tools. If they owned the outputs then no one would use their tool.

For example the CS5 product license states:

> ADOBE AND ITS SUPPLIERS OWN ALL INTELLECTUAL PROPERTY IN THE SOFTWARE. THE
>   SOFTWARE IS LICENSED, NOT SOLD. ADOBE PERMITS YOU TO COPY, DOWNLOAD,
>   INSTALL, USE, OR OTHERWISE BENEFIT FROM THE FUNCTIONALITY OR INTELLECTUAL
>   PROPERTY OF THE SOFTWARE ONLY IN ACCORDANCE WITH THE TERMS OF THIS
>   AGREEMENT.

You'll see a similar statement in other products. All of the Adobe EULAs can be accessed here:

- http://www.adobe.com/products/eulas/